# Помогите понять почему так происходит

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, list

Я только начинаю изучать программирование, но всегда спотыкаюсь на этой проблеме в Python.
Почему в этом случае список присваивается list[:] = new_list:

```
names=['name1','name2','name3','name4','name5','name6']

def print_name (list):
    for name in list:
        print(name)


def add_lastname (list):
    new_list = []
    while list:
        name = 'Last_name '+ list.pop(0)
        new_list.append(name)
    list[:] = new_list


add_lastname(names)
print_name(names)
```

А вот в этом случае нет list = new_list!

```
names=['name1','name2','name3','name4','name5','name6']

def print_name (list):
    for name in list:
        print(name)


def add_lastname (list):
    new_list = []
    while list:
        name = 'Last_name '+ list.pop(0)
        new_list.append(name)
    list = new_list


add_lastname(names)
print_name(names)
```

list[:] = new_list - так я функцией изменяю изначальный список
list = new_list - а так не изменяю

Я же обращаюсь к списку и в том и вдругом случае, зачем ему эти [:] - ведь это же создание копии списка или я не прав?

Comment: что означает "работает"? что означает "не работает"?

Comment: Я еще пытаюсь выйти из клина ) Да, функция чистит список и там и там, но почему в первом случае присвоение получается а вот во  втором нет

Comment: В первом случае заменяются все элементы в исходном списке. Во втором случае в локальную переменную list записывается новый список, а старый список никак не модифицируется.

Comment: Почему list[:] это ссылка на исходный список, а list на локальный. Эта конструкция [:] - создание среза всего исходного списка, т.е получается копия. Но тут это ссылка на исходный список. Во это я никак не могу понять.

Comment: Спасибо  я понял

Comment: "Эта конструкция [:] - создание среза всего исходного списка, т.е получается копия." - нет, при присваивании срезу это не создание копии, а замена элементов среза в исходном списке.

Comment: @Nikolaich Оформите ответ пожалуйста. И еще один момент, никогда не используйте зарезервированиые слова для имен переменных. Например 'list' как у вас в коде. Это считается серьезной ошибкой.